# How to exclude combinations that have less than 2 rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a df like this:

```
ID <- c("ID444","ID465","ID465","ID465","ID465","ID465","ID465")
Measurement <- c("Length","Width","Width","Length","Width","Length","Length")
PASSFAIL <- c("PASS","PASS","PASS","FAIL","FAIL","PASS","PASS")
df <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,PASSFAIL)
```

I then do a summary to see how many combinations are there for measurement and passfail.

```
unique <- summaryBy(Measurement~Measurement+PASSFAIL,data=df, FUN = function(x) {c(n=length(x))})
unique

      Measurement PASSFAIL Measurement.n
    1      Length     FAIL             1
    2      Length     PASS             3
    3       Width     FAIL             1
    4       Width     PASS             2
```

I would like to remove any combinations that are less than 2 or equal to 1. I am not knowing how to do that. I know this is a very simple logic but just not able to get it right. Could someone help me with that?

My **Desired output** is

```
     ID Measurement PASSFAIL
1 ID444      Length     PASS
2 ID465       Width     PASS
3 ID465       Width     PASS
4 ID465      Length     PASS
5 ID465      Length     PASS
```

Comment: are you looking for `df[df[,'PASSFAIL']=='PASS',]` ?

Comment: The data.table idiom is `setDT(df)[, if (.N>1) .SD, by=.(Measurement,PASSFAIL)]`... maybe some SQL like "having" syntax will be available later; there's a FR posted for it, anyway. For dplyr, `df %>% group_by(Measurement,PASSFAIL) %>% filter(n()>1)`

Comment: I think this is basically a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30745301/1191259 (and several other similar qs)

Comment: That dplyr syntax is exactly what I wanted. Works great on my bigger data set. Thanks @Frank